# Navigation in my drawer won't work ( ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined, js engine: hermes)

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app, react-native-drawer

I'm working on navigation drawer that allows me to navigate between pages when clicking on each one. However, whenever I try to click on any of the pages in the drawer, the error, " ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined, js engine: hermes" comes up. I am very new to react native and I'm not sure how to fix this. I am currently testing this on an android device if that helps.

Here's my code:

App.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LogInScreen from './Screens/LogInScreen';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import RecordHours from './Screens/DrawerComponents/RecordHours';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}}name="LogIn" component={LogInScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}}name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}}name="Record Hours" component={RecordHours} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Alert } from 'react-native'; // Add Alert import
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { getAuth, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
import RecordHours from './DrawerComponents/RecordHours';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const auth = getAuth();

const CustomDrawerContent = ({ navigation, ...props }) => {
  const handleSignOut = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        navigation.replace('LogIn');
      })
      .catch((error) => Alert.alert('Error', error.message));
  };  

  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label="Sign Out" onPress={handleSignOut} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
};



const MyDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent navigation={props.navigation} {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={App} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Record Hours" component={RecordHours} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};


const App = () => {
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(0);

  const increaseHours = () => {
    setHours(hours + 1);
  };

  const decreaseHours = () => {
    if (hours > 0) {
      setHours(hours - 1);
    }
  };

  const currentUserEmail = auth.currentUser ? auth.currentUser.email : '';

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text>Email: {currentUserEmail}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.hoursText}>Total Hours: {hours}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={increaseHours}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add Hour</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={decreaseHours}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Remove Hour</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  hoursText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#2196f3',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default function Apps() {
  return (
    <MyDrawer />
  );
}
```

LogInScreen.js

```
import { ImageBackground, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
// import React from 'react'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';



const LogInScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')


    const navigation = useNavigation()

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user){
                navigation.navigate("HomeScreen")
            }
        })

        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    const handleSignUp = () => {
        const auth = getAuth();
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log('Registered with  ', user.email)
                                    })
        .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
                        });
    }

    const handleLogin = () => {
        const auth = getAuth();
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log('Logged in with ', user.email)
                                        })
        .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        alert("Sign-in unsuccessfull: " + errorMessage)
        });
    }
      
  return (
    
    <>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={styles.container}
      >
              <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                  <TextInput
                      placeholder="Email"
                      value={email}
                      onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
                      style={styles.input} />

                  <TextInput
                      placeholder="Password"
                      value={password}
                      onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
                      style={styles.input}
                      secureTextEntry />
              </View>

              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={handleLogin}
                      style={styles.button}
                  >
                      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={handleSignUp}
                      style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
                  >
                      <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>

          </KeyboardAvoidingView></>
  )
}

export default LogInScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {

        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    inputContainer:{
        width:'80%'
    },
    input:{
        backgroundColor:'white',
        paddingHorizontal:15,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginTop: 5,
    },
    buttonContainer:{
        width:'60%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 40,
    },
    button:{
        backgroundColor: '#24A0ED',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 15,
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    buttonOutline:{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        marginTop: 5,
        borderColor: '#24A0ED',
        borderWidth: 2,
    },
    buttonText:{
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: '700',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    buttonOutlineText:{
        color: '#24A0ED',
        fontWeight: '700',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
})
```

RecordHours.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const RecordHours = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>RecordHours</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default RecordHours

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a circular dependency between `App.js` and `HomeScreen.js` files. In `App.js`, you are importing the `HomeScreen` component, and in `HomeScreen.js`, you are importing the `App` component. This circular dependency can lead to unexpected behavior.
To fix this, you should create a separate file for the drawer navigator and move the `MyDrawer` component from `HomeScreen.js` to the new file. Then, import the drawer navigator component in `App.js` and use it as the initial screen.

And Double-check that the screen names in your navigation stack match the ones used in the navigator.